# I can't update/add rows to 2 tables at once with auto-binded controls from datasets in visual studio c#

Tags: datagridview, dataset

These are my codes in the second table that can't save:

```
 if (dgvSales.RowCount == 0)
        {
            int recCountS = 0;
            while (recCountS < dgvRec.RowCount - 1)
            {
                DataRow row = posalesDataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
                row[0] = (posalesDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count + 1);
                row[1] = (dgvRec.Rows[recCountS].Cells[0].Value);
                row[2] = dtpDSold.Value;
                row[3] = Convert.ToInt32(dgvRec.Rows[recCountS].Cells[2].Value);
                row[4] = Convert.ToInt32(dgvRec.Rows[recCountS].Cells[3].Value);
                posalesDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
                MessageBox.Show(row[1] + " Sales saved.");
                recCountS++;
            }
```

other block of codes that updates the other table is working, but this one does not. it shows the added row to the datagridview after adding, which means, it does add. but, after i exit the form, and open it again, it is not there anymore. thanks in advance for those who can help :)

Comment: You mention, "after I exit the form."  Are the two `DataGridView` on separate forms?  Are you instantiating the form containing the 2nd view every time it's opened?

Comment: The two datagridviews are on the same form, and i'm using datasource's drag and drop control for both datagridviews. What do you mean, sir, by 2nd "view"? thank you sir btw for replying..

Comment: I just meant 2nd `DataGridView`.  So, both are on the same form, and both add new rows successfully, but after exiting and reopening one saves but the other does not?  The problem is not likely what I thought.

Comment: can i send you the solution file so you could check on it? if that won't trouble you.

Comment: i've sent it to you.